# get the installed path of a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, installation

I'm nearly ready to distribute my vb.net application. I have several picturebox files which are loaded currently from c:/temp

I need to change this directory to one that will be OK to use when the user installs it to their PC.

My question is how can I do this? Is there a way to get the installation path, then use that within the code as a variable? `eg: myInstalledPath & "/xxx.jpg"`

Or... would it be better for me to use mypictures within the mydocuments structure? I'd rather keep all the image files created in a folder which is more hidden from the user (by hidden I mean not cluttering up their own image folders!)

I've tried searching for this, but I seem to get varying results with no real answers... (possibly searching for the wrong thing!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the [ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with:

```
Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Then you'll know where the application is residing.
As for where to save your images a common location is the AppData folder.
You can get it like this:

```
Dim appDataPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

The AppData folder is by default a hidden folder so that satisfies your requirements.